# The how(goal) question to show proof of conclusion the system arrived in prolog

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I have created a bird identifying system which identifies the bird family based on some knowledge base. The identification process only happens with user answering the yes or no for the questions prompted. This is a basic sample code.I had used a history/3 predicate which asserted the values but i have removed it for now to post here.The main file which loads the knowledge base is shown below:

```
go :-
greeting,
repeat,
write('> '),
read(X),
do(X),
X == quit.

greeting :-
write('This is the Native Prolog shell.'), nl,
write('Enter load, consult, or quit at the prompt.'), nl.
do(load) :- load_kb, !.
do(consult) :- solve, !.
do(quit).
do(X) :-
write(X),
write('is not a legal command.'), nl,
fail.

load_kb :-
write('Enter file name: '),
read(F),
reconsult(F).

solve :-
retractall(known(_,_,_)),
top_goal(X),
write('The answer is '), write(X), nl.

solve :-
write('No answer found.'), nl.

ask(A,V):-  
known(yes,A,V),!. %%% succeed if true.

ask(A,V):-
    known(_,A,V), %%% fail If false.
    !,fail.

ask(A,V):- 
write(A: V),      %%% ask user
write('?:'),  
read(Y),          %%% get the answer
asserta(known(Y,A,V)), %%% remember it    
Y == yes.         %%% succeed or fail.

menuask(A,V,MenuList):-   
write('What is the value for'),write(A), %%% asking user
write('?'),nl,  
write(MenuList),
read(X),                       %%% get the value
check_val(X,A,V,_),            %%% checks the value entered is in the menu.
asserta(known(yes,A,X)),       %%% if yes remembers it.
X==V.

check_val(X,_,_,MenuList):-member(X,MenuList).

check_val(X, A, V, MenuList) :
write(X), 
write(' is not a legal value, try again.'), nl,
menuask(A, V, MenuList).
```

I have used known/3 predicate to store the user entered values. I am getting the output but i also want to get the proof of conclusion when asked how(goal).

Example: I get the output perfectly as shown below.

```
?- go.
This is the Native Prolog shell.
Enter load, consult, or quit at the prompt.
> load.
Enter file name: |: load.
> |: consult.
nostrils:external_tubular?:|: yes.
live:at_sea?:|: yes.
bill:hooked?:|: yes.
What is the value forsize?
[large,plump,medium,small]|: large.
wings:long_narrow?:|: yes.
color:white?:|: yes.
The answer is laysan_albatross
```

But i also want to get this:

```
?- how(laysan_albatross).
bird(laysan_albatross): family(albatross)color(white)
family(albatross): order(tubenose)size(large)wings(long_narrow)
order(tubenose): nostrils(external_tubular)live(at_sea)bill(hooked)
```

Apparently this is tracing back the rules used in the process but i don't know how to crack it. I am stuck in this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

There's the trace predicate (SWI-Prolog has gtrace, which is easier to understand).

If you want an explanation rather than a trace, search for "meta-circular interpreter". It's also in most Prolog textbooks; if you can't understand one, try another (I happen to like O'Keefe's Craft of Prolog but it can be a bit overwhelming).

One example of such an interpreter is in http://www.amzi.com/distribution/files/xsip_book.pdf ... look for the "Why Questions" section (page 41). The code is probably more complex than you need for your example, though.

Comment: I know how it traces , but the thing is i dunno how to traverse back to the sub-goals to provide the proof. Like to show it is bird(x) because its family(x), it is family(X) because it is order(X), it is order(X) because the asserted known/3 facts are true. I want to go like this and print them out . That's where im stuck. I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: I added a pointer to the Amzi book. But the code is probably more complex than you need.